# Clarification of replace and extra sections in composer.json for TYPO3 extensions

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

**Update** (*Aug 17, 2020*): the section `"my_ext_key": "self.version"` is no longer found in newer examples or in [helhum/composer.json](https://gist.github.com/helhum/0ffd82525c90f305b81a8285329eb4f8). See clarifications below.

---

There are several examples for composer.json for TYPO3 around. Some include a replace section with something like the following:

---

**replace:**

```
"replace": {
    "my_ext_key": "self.version",
    "typo3-ter/my-ext-key": "self.version"
},
```

or

```
"replace": {
    "vendorname/my-extension": "self.version",
    "typo3-ter/my-extension": "self.version"
},
```

https://wiki.typo3.org/Composer#Extension_key_.2F_composer_name

And / or an **extra** section

```
"extra": {
    "typo3/cms": {
        "extension-key": "extension_key"
    }
}
```

When are these sections necessary, what do they do and what is recommended (for TYPO3 extensions)? Are there differences between TYPO3 versions specific to these sections?

---

Specifically:

1. The second line in the replace example

   ```
   "typo3-ter/my-ext-key": "self.version"
   ```

   for example, makes sense if extension was published in TER and was
   available from composer.typo3.org, I guess. If extension was only
   available via packagist, it does not really make sense to include it.
2. About the first line of replace, when is this necessary and what does it do?

   ```
   "my_ext_key": "self.version",
   ```

   Usually, replace it used to replace some other package, e.g. as a drop-in-replacement which is explained for example [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#replace). This section was available in a previous example composer.json but has now been removed (see [helhum/composer.json](https://gist.github.com/helhum/0ffd82525c90f305b81a8285329eb4f8/revisions)). Also, it would now cause a warning on `composer validate`, see also [comment](https://gist.github.com/helhum/0ffd82525c90f305b81a8285329eb4f8#gistcomment-3239391). Is it still necessary for older TYPO3 versions?
3. The extra part maps the extension key (with underscore) to package name (with dash). However, this is already the default. So, when is this required or can it be removed entirely?

Comment: Maybe to explain the context of this question: There are several examples floating around and it's not so easy to figure out what the authoritative resource is for TYPO3 here. Also, I believe the line with typo3-ter is not really necessary if you use Packagist.

Comment: Which of these parts look undocumented to you? https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#replace hasn't been fundamentally changed for years

Comment: This is a question pretty specific to TYPO3. I updated the question and hopefully clarified it a bit. What added to my confusion was that current practice of using both replace and extra to specifiy the extension key has changed over time, I did not find explanations for everything and I don't just need any example I can use but I would like to fully understand it better as I am also involved in documentation contribution. I can't document stuff I only vaguely understand or where I assume it is like this, but not really sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [official composer documentation for replace](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#replace) states:

> Lists packages that are replaced by this package. This allows you to fork a package, publish it under a different name with its own version numbers, while packages requiring the original package continue to work with your fork because it replaces the original package.
>
> This is also useful for packages that contain sub-packages, for example the main symfony/symfony package contains all the Symfony Components which are also available as individual packages. If you require the main package it will automatically fulfill any requirement of one of the individual components, since it replaces them.
>
> Caution is advised when using replace for the sub-package purpose explained above. You should then typically only replace using self.version as a version constraint, to make sure the main package only replaces the sub-packages of that exact version, and not any other version, which would be incorrect.

For a more [TYPO3 related explanation of the composer.json replace property](https://insight.helhum.io/post/148886148725/composerjson-specification-for-typo3-extensions) there is an explanation available provided by Helhum:

> The replace property MUST be provided if the composer package name part does not match the extension name and is highly recommended thus SHOULD be provided in any case. If it is provided, the first replace value MUST match exactly the extension key and the second replace value SHOULD match the TER package key (extension key prefixed with “typo3-ter/” and with underscores (_) replaced with dashes (-). The version constraint MUST exactly be `self.version`

For additional information please follow the links as they contain further information.

Comment: Thanks you. I was hoping for a little more information on using this with TYPO3.

Comment: I‘ve just updated my answer with another link to a more TYPO3 related answer of your question, but I recommend to read both of them.

Comment: I don't wish to be annoying. I think I have all I need. But in general StackOverflow recommends: "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline." https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: I've updated the answer with context from the sources in case they are not availabe.